# Custom Table View Cell with UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have this design which combination of View Controller and static Table View Controller. I have tried using View Controller at the top and embedded table View Controller at bottom, but i can't figure out how to pass data to two VC simulatneously.

[image]

what's the best practice to implement this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `container view` in your ViewController:

[image]

This automatically creates a relationship segue:

[image]

And finally you can access the embedded ViewControllers through `prepareForSegue`:

```
class MyMainViewController {
    var embeddedVC1: MyEmbeddedViewController1!
    var embeddedVC2: MyEmbeddedViewController2!
    var embeddedVC3: MyEmbeddedViewController3!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Embedded1" {
            self.embeddedVC1 = segue.destinationViewController as? MyEmbeddedViewController1
        } else if segue.identifier == "Embedded2" {
            self.embeddedVC2 = segue.destinationViewController as? MyEmbeddedViewController2
        } else if segue.identifier == "Embedded3" {
            self.embeddedVC3 = segue.destinationViewController as? MyEmbeddedViewController3
        }
    }

}
```

Since we now have the embedded view controller instances stored in attributes of our View Controller, we can send data to the embedded view controllers in any other function.

Sending data back however, requires delegation through [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267).